# Would an infinite random sequence of real numbers contain repetitions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

If random real numbers are selected from the set of all real numbers, for an infinite number of iterations, what is the likelihood of repetitions occurring?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is 0.  For a repitition to occur at iteration n then that means r_n is one of the n previous.  The probability of that is n/card(Real) = 0.  The sum of these 0 probabilities is 0.

Comment: infinite like countably infinite? uncountably infinite? which uncountable infinite then?

Comment: *How* the random selection is done may well matter; e.g., selection by means of some algorithm (since the set of computable reals is countable, unlike $\mathbb{R}$). Note that "random" does not imply a uniform distribution.

Comment: Perhaps I mean each choice is independent of the others, if that helps?

Comment: @mattecapu Good point. For 2^$\aleph_0$ iterations p=1.

Answer (score 16):

There is no such thing as "random real numbers selected from the set of all real numbers".  Assuming what you mean is that you are taking independent samples $X_n$ from some continuous probability distribution, then yes, for any fixed $n \ne m$, the probability $\mathbb P(X_n = X_m)$ that $X_n = X_m$ is $0$, and so by countable additivity the probability of a repeat is also $0$.

Comment: Even if the probability is zero wouldn't that only mean the probability that "the next number chosen is the same as the previous one" is zero? And that with an infinitely large sequence, everything would occur in every order, including an infinite sequence of identical numbers?

Comment: No, for every $m \ne n$, the probability that the $m$'th and $n$'th are the same is $0$.  The probability of the union of **countably** many events, each of probability $0$, is $0$.  That's called countable additivity.

Comment: Are real numbers countable?

Comment: @JingWang: You're only selecting countably many of them.

Comment: So would the probability of a repetition still be 0 if we limited ourselves to natural numbers? I'm guessing so.

Comment: @ChrisMoore: No. This answer assumes that the OP intended a continuous probability distribution, where the probability of any specific value is 0. No such distribution exists over the natural numbers, so such an assumption would clearly be false there. (To see why, we can apply the same countable additivity that the answer mentions: if the probability of each natural number is 0, then the total probability of all natural numbers would have to be zero.) *[continued]*

Comment: @ChrisMoore: *[continued]* So if we limit ourselves to the natural numbers, then at least one number *n* must have nonzero probability, in which case the probability goes to 1 that *n* appears multiple times.

Comment: @ruakh Why natural numbers? It seems the OP is interested in real numbers, or simply $[0,1]$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: But I wasn't talking to the OP, I was talking to Chris Moore, whose question was explicitly about natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to say just how to select a "random real number". Even selecting a random positive integer is tricky - any individual number will be chosen with zero probability.

So this is not an official mathematical answer to your question, since you haven't specified the selection method:

I'm quite sure that any reasonable way you do it you'll find the likelihood of repetitions is zero. @fleablood 's comment explains why. The probability for any particular number must be $0$ so the probability of a repeat in any finite sequence is $0$. That will also be true for any  countable sequence.

The question does kind of specify countability when it says "an infinite number of iterations" but if that infinity is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ the question is much murkier.

Comment: Would it be okay to say the probability of iteration n being a repeat is that r_n is one of n values and the probability of that is 0.  The probability of a repeat never happening is lim 1 -0^n = 1.  I'd accept that, would you?

Comment: @fleablood Interesting question. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

(I read the problem too quickly and my entire first attempt was way off. Feel free to skip past the part that I've indented with block-quotes)

> HINT: I would look at what happens when you pick numbers from "1" to
>   "n", find a function that shows what happens when you repeat "n"
>   times, then find the limit as "n" goes to infinity.
>
> Do you know how to set this up?
>
> ORIGINAL EDIT "No I don't know how to" Very well then, let's start
>   with $n=5$
>
> a) If you are referring to repetition *anywhere* in the sequence, then
>   sequences like 1-4-3-5-3 or 2-5-4-1-2 would all count, leaving *only*
>   the sequences that only contain each number one time: 1-3-4-2-5,
>   2-4-3-5-1, 5-3-4-1-2...
>
> Out of the total $5^5 = 3125$ combinations, this leaves $5! =
> > 5*4*3*2*1 = 120$ that do not repeat contain repetition against
>   $3125-120 = 3005$ combinations that do (3.84% without repetition,
>   96.16% with). Whereas if $n=10$, then we have $10^{10} = 10$ billion combinations, only $10! = 10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 = 3,628,800$ of which
>   use each number exactly once without repetition (0.036288% without
>   repetition, 99.963712% with).
>
> As $n$ gets larger and larger, the probability $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ that
>   each number from 1 to $n$ is used once and only once approaches 0,
>   approaching a 100% chance as $n$ approaches infinity that there will
>   be at least one repetition at some point in the sequence.
>
> b) Or, if you only mean repetition from one number to the next
>   (1-3-4-1-5 doesn't count as repetition, but 2-3-3-1-4 does), then you
>   have $n-1$ pairs of adjacent numbers and a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance that
>   any given pair is a match (whatever the first number is, there are $n$
>   possibilities for what the next one will be).
>
> The odds that one given pair does not match are
>   $\frac{n-1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$, and the odds that *none* of the $n-1$
>   pairs match equals $(\frac{n-1}{n})^{n-1}= (1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}$. Do
>   you know how to find $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}$?

2nd EDIT: And I just realized I was supposed to be going by "all real numbers" in my previous two examples.

In any case, the set of all real numbers (integer, rational, irrational algebraic, irrational transcendental) is uncountably infinite, whereas the length of the sequence (the first number, the second, the third ... the billionth ... the googol-th ...) would be countably infinite.

Both versions of repetition that I looked at would actually have a 0% chance of occurring.

Comment: No I don't know how to

Comment: @JingWang Just finished elaborating.

Comment: I think there's a problem with this answer. You seem to be assuming that the first $n$ numbers in the sequence are chosen from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. In that case the probability that you have a permutation does in fact approach $0$. But in fact each segment of length $n$ is a random sequence of $n$ real numbers of any size.

Comment: @EthanBolker It seemed like first seeing what the functions would look like with finite numbers, secondly seeing what happens when we take the limit as the numbers approach infinity, would work better than inventing infinite functions from scratch.

Comment: @Simpson17866 thank you for showing this, however it seems like you are talking about Natural numbers rather than Real numbers? (I guess you've answered my second question before I even asked it).

Comment: @JingWang Oh, I see where I was going sideways now. Editing again.